# Get Wikipedia raw tags directly?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there a URL to get the raw tags of a Wikipedia entry directly, not the HTML? That is, I want to get only things like this,

```
{{about|the cat species that is commonly kept as a pet|the cat family|Felidae|other uses|Cat (disambiguation)|and|Cats (disambiguation)}}....
```

not,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Cat - Wikipedia</title> ....
```

I have sourced Google but could not find the answer. The closest URL I could find is something like `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat&action=edit`, I can extract tags from it, but it still contains unnecessary HTML stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "tags" is the [Wikitext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikitext) syntax. It can be obtained for any page by using the "raw" action, like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat&action=raw. Note that you'll obtain the exact same content as the action=edit that you were using, there is no other version without "unnecessary HTML stuff".